# Transaction check error on yum-update for package libedit

Tags: centos, yum

I'm fairly new to managing a server (sandbox development on a linode VPS), and I haven't run updates in a while.

I just decided to login as root and run "yum update" to update all of the software packages on the box. I'm running CentOS 5.6.

After unning it, it tells me it will install 1 package and upgrade 46. I select yes, and when it runs a transaction test I get this errro:

Transaction Check Error:
  package libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.x86_64 (which is newer than libedit-3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art.i386) is already installed

I tried googling around for how to handle this, but it's hard with such a specific error. Can anyone give me guidance on how to handle resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are trying to install an i386 package instead of an x86_64 package. If you don't have the 32bit libraries installed it may not install and fail at this point. What I have done when I have had this issue is the following:

```
cd /var/tmp
yum remove libedit
wget http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/5/x86_64/RPMS/libedit-3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art.x86_64.rpm
yum install glibc
rpm -Uvh libedit-3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Ah okay. Instead of removing just that one package, I decided to remove them all. See #22 here: http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-357346ff0bf7c14b0849c3bcce39677aaca528e9

Thanks!